# Two Vinogradovs? Is one the son of the other?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ho.history-overview, analytic-number-theory

Forgive me for my ignorance, but I'm very surprised to learn that there are [two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Matveyevich_Vinogradov) [Vinogradovs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Askold_Ivanovich_Vinogradov), both famous in the field of analytic number theory. Guessing from their names and [the Russian naming convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patronymic), is one the son of the other?

Comment: Could you guys tell me whether you thought they were different people previously, or just how ignorant I am.

Comment: The older Vinogradov was never married, and had no (official) children. Ivan is a common name in Russia (and it was even more common back then), so the naming convention does not imply anything here.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek So there are two Vinogradovs working on remarkably overlapping topics, including in particular the [large sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_sieve). What a miracle!

Comment: Here is a list of reknown people with last name Vinogradov from Russian wikipedia: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2.

Comment: Mathscinet has 59 Vinogradov's. The most famous one is Ivan Matveevich. What are the initials of the other Vinogradov you are asking about?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko The other one is Askold Ivanovich Vinogradov, in the Bomberi-Vinogradov theorem.

Comment: I've never figured out Markov (Markoff). Markov processes seems to be a different person from Markov Numbers in number theory. Possibly related.

Comment: @WillJagy, why do you think those two Markovs are different?

Comment: @WillJagy two Markovs you are talking about are the same person Andrei Andreevich Markov, though usually spelling differently (Markov processes, but Markoff triples). But please do not identify him with his son, constructive logician Andrei Andreevich Markov junior.

Comment: http://hsm.stackexchange.com/ ??

Comment: @Will Jagy: there were at least 3 famous Markov's from one family: Andrei Andreevich (approximation, Markov processes, number theory, continued fractions, differential equations etc.) his brother Vladimir ( Markov's Inequality), and his son, with exactly the same name as the father (logician).

Comment: @KConrad, I was never sure, they just seemed different topics.

Comment: @FedorPetrov, that is something. I found some biography but it was in Russian and did not clear up anything.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, this begins to make sense. The impressions I had were two very different topics, then a length of time that seemed to fit father and son rather than one person. So, brothers and one son.

Comment: @Will Jagy: English Wikipedia has very decent articles on each of the three. If you search on Markov, it gives a list of persons with this last name, not too long, in which the brothers and the son are the only mathematicians. The articles summarize their most famous contributions.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, I just found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrei_Markov on your suggestion, I will see if I can find it without the Andrei; hmmm, not yet, but I bet the page for the elder mentions Vladimir. Well, as to separate articles, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Markov  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Andreevich_Markov  and  Junior: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Markov,_Jr. Thanks

Comment: So you guys are telling me tenary Goldbach conjecture and Bomberi-Vinogradov are not research level math?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer seems to be no. It is hard to find direct confirmation, but every time their names are mentioned together it is made clear that there's no relationship.

> The Russian mathematician Askold Ivanovich Vinogradov is not to be
>   confused with the other Russian mathematician (the mathematical
>   great-grandchild of Pafnuty Lvovich Chebyshev) whose work is at the
>   heart of this paper: Ivan Matveyevich Vinogradov.

*(Newsletter of the European Mathematical Society, issue 90)*

> There is a theorem due to Askold Ivanovich Vinogradov (1929-2005, not
>   to be confused with another and more famous Russian mathematician,
>   Ivan Matveevich Vinogradov, 1891-1988) that states...

*Ian Hacking, Why Is There Philosophy of Mathematics At All?*

In this [obituary in the Russian Mathematical Surveys](http://www.numbertheory.org/obituaries/RMS/vinogradov/obituary/page1.html) there's also no mention of him having children, let alone another somewhat famous soviet mathematician.

Ivan Matveyevich Vinogradov's [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Matveyevich_Vinogradov#Personality_and_career) also mentions that he never married.